# ¿Porque mi metodo no imprime la informacion?

Tags: java, lista

Estoy haciendo un método que selecciona el objeto de tipo Actividad de una lista enlazada que dentro de esta tiene una cola de tareas, lo que trato de hacer con mi metodo es primero obtener el valor del nodo que tiene la actividad seleccionada, cuando lo hago luego creo un nodo de Tarea para recorrer los nodos de tarea de la cola:

```
  public void listarTareasColas() {
    String info = "Los ID y nombres que hay en la cola son: \n";

    Actividad index = tablaActividades.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(index.getNombre().toString());

    NodoDoble<Actividad> nododoble = modelFactoryController.getMiPrincipal().getListaActividades()
            .buscarNodo(index);

    Nodo<Tarea> tarea = nododoble.getValorNodo().getColaTareas().getPrimero();
    while (tarea != null) {
        info += "ID de la tarea" + tarea.getValorNodo().getId() + "Nombre de la tarea"
                + tarea.getValorNodo().getNombre();
        System.out.println("Los ID y nombres que hay en la cola son: \n" + tarea.getValorNodo().getId()
                + "Nombre de la tarea" + tarea.getValorNodo().getNombre());
        info += "\n";
        tarea = tarea.getSiguienteNodo();

        System.out.println(info);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, info);
}
```

El metodo de :

```
modelFactoryController.getMiPrincipal().getListaActividades().buscarNodo(index);
```

Lo que hace es:

```
/**
 * Devuelve un nodo que contenga un dato específico
 * 
 * @param dato Dato a buscar
 * @return Nodo
 */
public NodoDoble<T> buscarNodo(T dato) {

    NodoDoble<T> aux = nodoPrimero;

    while (aux != null) {
        if (aux.getValorNodo().equals(dato)) {
            return aux;
        }
        aux = aux.getSiguienteNodo();
    }

    return null;
}
```

He llegado a pensar que quizas la variable: `String info=""` se actualiza o solo vive dentro del while.

Answer (score 0):

Mencionas que este método "Devuelve un nodo que contenga un dato específico", pero en realidad no es así ya que esta retornando siempre un valor null, por esa razón nunca imprimirás valores obtenidos por este método:

```
public NodoDoble<T> buscarNodo(T dato) {
    ...
    ...
    return null;
}
```

debe retornar un valor de tipo `NodoDoble<T>`  modifica tu método `buscarNodo()`:

```
public NodoDoble<T> buscarNodo(T dato) {

    NodoDoble<T> aux = nodoPrimero;

    while (aux != null) {
        if (aux.getValorNodo().equals(dato)) {
            return aux;
        }
        aux = aux.getSiguienteNodo();
    }

    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Modifique el metodo que me dijiste y aun asi nada, agregue un Syso() antes de recorrerlos y me arroja java.lang.NullPointerException` Exactamente por esta linea: ` System.out.println(tarea.getValorNodo().getNombre().toString());` al parecer en realidad no captura el nodo... quizas no lo esta retornando nunca o no lo se...

Comment: Ese es otro detalle, ahora buscarNodo() ya obtiene un valor pero ahora debes verifica que datos tiene "tarea" aquí:  Nodo<Tarea> tarea = nododoble.getValorNodo().getColaTareas().getPrimero();